# Dynamic IP address for website. Can it have negative impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, amazon-aws, route53

We want to start using AWS elastic beanstalk + Route53 setup for hosting our website. The major problem is that AWS elastic beanstalk is load balancer and will return different IP addresses after each website deployment (but IP will always be in the same geo region).

Can it potentially harm our SEO strategy?

Comment: Not as you describe it. Dynamic IP addresses for websites within a subscriber space (think broadband) using DDNS will.

Answer (score 1):

Its should not impact SEO. You just have to use a custom domain for your Elastic Beanstalk application, such as http://myapp.example.com, by creating a CNAME with your DNS provider that maps your custom domain name to your Elastic Beanstalk URL.